# Enumerating the shell for devices

Tags: c#, shell, com

There are two practical ways to access the Shell Namespace from C#, the MS WindowsApiCodePack bridge to `IShellFolder` and related stuff (available on NuGet), or referencing Shell32 (Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation) directly. The two approaches are basically similar, although the first has more features (what I'm mostly interested in is support for image thumbnails and better file copying capabilities).

Enumerating the *This PC* folder is done either as:

```
string ThisPC = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}";
var folder = ShellFolder.FromParsingName(ThisPC) as ShellFolder;
foreach (var child in folder)
```

or

```
var shellAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
object shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellAppType);
var ThisPC = (Folder)shellAppType.InvokeMember("NameSpace", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shell, new object[] { 0x11 });
foreach (FolderItem child in ThisPC.Items())
```

but there is a very important difference between the two: the second enumerates devices like attached phones while the first does not. I used the fact that the Api Code Pack is open source and modified the `ShellFolderItems` constructor (this is what `ShellFolder` iterates on) to try

```
HResult hr = nativeShellFolder.NativeShellFolder.EnumObjects(
  IntPtr.Zero,
  //ShellNativeMethods.ShellFolderEnumerationOptions.IncludeHidden | ShellNativeMethods.ShellFolderEnumerationOptions.IncludeSuperHidden |
  //ShellNativeMethods.ShellFolderEnumerationOptions.Shareable |
  ShellNativeMethods.ShellFolderEnumerationOptions.Folders | ShellNativeMethods.ShellFolderEnumerationOptions.NonFolders | ShellNativeMethods.ShellFolderEnumerationOptions.Storage,
  out nativeEnumIdList);
```

The code originally filtered for Folders and NonFolders but this leaves out the phones in the first place. So I added Storage, the hidden things, all combinations that I can think of, but no difference at all. Some filter combinations will remove items already enumerated but none will increase it to devices.

What could I do to make the first approach enumerate just like the second?

*Update:* to make to easier to reproduce, here is the whole program, really not much more than what's described above:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
using Shell32;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
  class Program {

    private static void ShellObjects1() {
      string ThisPC = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}";
      var folder = ShellFolder.FromParsingName(ThisPC) as ShellFolder;
      foreach (var child in folder)
        Console.WriteLine($"{child.Name} = {child.ParsingName}");
    }

    private static void ShellObjects2() {
      var shellAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
      object shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellAppType);
      var ThisPC = (Folder)shellAppType.InvokeMember("NameSpace", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shell, new object[] { 0x11 });
      foreach (FolderItem child in ThisPC.Items())
        Console.WriteLine($"{child.Name} = {child.Path}");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Console.WriteLine("WindowsAPICodePack");
      ShellObjects1();
      Console.WriteLine();

      Console.WriteLine("Shell32");
      ShellObjects2();
      Console.WriteLine();
    }

  }
}
```

You should add a reference to Microsoft Shell from among the COM items and install the Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell NuGet package to compile it. As I run this, the two lists will be almost identical. Just like in the Explorer window, first the Folders, then the Drives. But in the second list there will be an extra entry in between: a device. Just like in Explorer. That item is lacking from the first list.

Comment: Have you tried both with the same bitness (32 vs 64)? Also why do you pass ShellNativeMethods.ShellFolderEnumerationOptions.Storage? This filters on items with SFGAO_STORAGE flag (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762589.aspx) . All items don't have that flag. Folders and NonFolders is really the default filter.

Comment: I used AnyCPU. Because, as I mentioned, I tried all combinations. The MS source originally only specifies Folders and NonFolders, and because it didn't enumerate phones in the first place, I started to experiment with other flags as well. No combination gives the results that I can see from the Shell32 call.

Comment: This is very unexpected. The IShellFolder::EnumObjects method is the mother of all enumerations. There's no other way. If I write a shell folder namespace extension, it will be called *exclusively* on this interface. Can you provide some code or steps to help reproduce ? I can't reproduce.

Comment: I can copy the program in its entirety but it's really not much more than what's up there. A simple console app, with that two enumerations, both `foreach` simply print the name and parsing name of each item. The two printouts will be different: the first will not report the devices while the second will. Tried on several different machines, W10 Creator, 64-bit, various phones. Actually, I never saw the devices enumerated in my life (apart from Win itself in it Explorer, of course, I mean programmatically). Using Shell32 was the first time I ever saw them appear.

Comment: The good news is: I can reproduce, and only the APIPack does this. If I use C++ IEnumShellItems or IShellFolder::EnumObjects, it does return the phone which is ok. The bad news is: I don't understand so far why the APIPack does that. Everything seems declared correctly, in fact exactly the same as what I do in C++... I'll try to dig further...

Comment: IShellFolder is very old and might have backcompat behavior.  Target at least .NET 4.5 so Vista additions are enabled, try IShellFolder2.

Comment: Thanks. If all else fails, I could write a shim in C++/CLI to bridge this but... I tried something and I wonder if it helps. If I take the shell path returned by Shell32 and try to use it with the pack to get the folder directly, here is the exception I get: " Interface not registered. Failed to find proxy registration for IID: {ADD8BA80-002B-11D0-8F0F-00C04FD7D062}." (This should be IDelegateFolder, I guess.)

Comment: @Hans Passant: uhh, it never occurred me to check what the ApiPack source is set to, it's 3.5, you might be on to something... :-) Simply changing it brings up a lot of errors, I'l delve into it.

Comment: Now I test again, and I don't reproduce it anymore... (I've also tested pure C++ code). All my tests and your tests now show the phone (it's an IPhone BTW). Here is a c# code that is equivalent to C/C++ interfaces: https://gist.github.com/smourier/c7771d4d5351c702f94118a0244856c8 can you test it and see if it changes anything? Your C/C++ shim would do exactly the same as this or use IEnumShellItems, but all that is supposed to be 100% equivalent

Comment: Right now I'm getting a fat access violation with your sample but I'll keep trying. :-) I also started to go a similar route, not C++ but simple C#, just the necessary interfaces with copying the structures and enums from the Code Pack to spare typing.

Comment: With a couple of small modifications (sent as comment to your gist, basically ref Guids) I could make it run. And you know what? No phone. :-) Just the same with the modified, simple IShellFolder I compiled in the meantime, just copied over what was necessary to make it run. Everything perfect but no phone. Shell32 still shows it flawlessly.

Comment: I also tried IEnumShellItems this time. Same results: no phone. Shell32 keeps working all right, so this must be something really sinister. Time to reverse engineer what it does?

Comment: Enumeration would be just one hurdle. There would be no problem enumerating with Shell32 and then working with the items using the traditional methods. But I can't pair them. `SHCreateItemFromParsingName()` refuses to parse the shell path I get for the phone, with the error that the interface is not registered. *Failed to find proxy registration for IID: {ADD8BA80-002B-11D0-8F0F-00C04FD7D062}.* I think we can safely assume that this is something the phones require and the later Shell32 provides somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, my dear and by thunder, it was the age old STAThread missing. Kind of misleading because the bulk of it was working, so it's probably the `IDelegateFolder` mentioned near the end of the comments that made that single interface miss the beat.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args) {
```